# Multiple routes same action .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create an anchor element in .cshtml choosing a specific route between multiples.

**Controller:**

```cs
[Route(""), Route("Products")]
public class ProductsController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet, Route("Search"), Route("Category/{category}")]
    public IActionResult SearchAction(string query, string category)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**.cshtml:**

```cshtml
//This two options return "Search?category=A", but I don't want the first route
<a href="@Url.Action("SearchAction", "Products", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="SearchAction" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>

//This return null, I want to define which route will be chosen
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Search", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Products/Search", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Search" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Products/Search" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Products/Category", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Category" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Products/Category" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Category/A">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Products/Category/A">Link</a>
```

Comment: You'll need to name the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi)**

> You'll need to name the routes.

I had to name the routes, but this led me to another problem, routes should have a unique template to be named.
So I removed the route from the controller and specified only in the action.

```cs
public class ProductsController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet, Route("Products/Search", Name = "Products/Search"), Route("Category/{category}", Name = "Products/Category")]
    public IActionResult SearchAction(string query, string category)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

An I was able to use like this:

```cshtml
<a asp-route="Products/Category" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Products/Category", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
<a asp-route="Products/Search" asp-route-category="A">Link</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Products/Search", new { category = "A" })">Link</a>
```